# Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Error response received for message <get-frame-manager-configuration>

Tags: angular, typescript, api, asynchronous, promise

I have first time in my life error from my title:
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Error response received for message .
I don't have any idea what making that error, but fortunately I have only one api call currently in my app.
I headed I should add some catch or promise.all, but I don't know where and every attempt fails. There is my code:

component.ts:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.attractionService.getAttractions().then((results) => {
      results.forEach((attraction: { id: number; name: string; description: string; type: string; distance: string | undefined; imagePath: string | undefined; }) => {
        this.section2ndModelAttractions.push(
          new Card(
            attraction.id,
            attraction.name,
            attraction.description,
            attraction.type,
            attraction.distance,
            attraction.imagePath
          )
        )
      })
    })
  }
```

And my attraction service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AttractionService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async getAttractions(): Promise<any> {
    return firstValueFrom(this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:7273/api/Attraction/All"));
  }
}
```

Somebody can tell me what I should do with my code to fix that error? Or maybe you guys need more details to fix it, I will provide what you need to fix that.

#Edit 1

I commented all code above and remove async on ngOnInit and I still have this error. I also posted whole error in edit below. I don't know what causes that error. How to get to the source of it?

Error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Error response received for message <get-frame-manager-configuration>
PromiseEmptyOnRejected
PromiseReactionJob
```

#Edit 2

I found something important! Error only appears in safari browser on macOS.

Comment: Anyone seeing this, disable 1Password extension and try again. This seems to be an issue if Safari with that one.